# Detecting when user unlinks alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm implementing an Alexa Smart Home skill and I want to know if a user is still using the app after a while.

Google Home, for example, sends a request when I unlink my app from the Google Smarthome app. I need to know it to disable sending updates to Amazon Alexa gateway if a user isn't using the skill anymore.

What the best way of doing it? Alexa documentation doesn't talk about it.

Can I rely on just checking if the user has a expired OAuth tokens? E.g. if expired for more than a day, mark user as inactive.

Another thing I'm going to test out tomorrow is just see the gateway response after having unlinked the skill. But for my case it wouldn't be good option anyway, as I will only know the user state after a physical change and trying to submit it and have it possibly fail. Which can happen after days or weeks, so it isn't that reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate with Alexa Skill Events and get notification when user disables the Skill.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-events-in-alexa-skills.html#skill-disabled-event.

The `SkillDisabled` event only contains user_id (i.e. no access token). So you would also need to listen for the `SkillAccountLinked` event so you can link that user_id with your own user identifier.

Your Smart Home Skill manifest should look like this:

```
{
  "manifest": {
    "publishingInformation": {
      "locales": {
        "en-US": {
          "summary": "...",
          "examplePhrases": [
            "Alexa, ...",
            "Alexa, ...",
            "Alexa, ..."
          ],
          "keywords": [],
          "name": "...",
          "smallIconUri": "...",
          "description": "...",
          "largeIconUri": "..."
        }
      },
      "isAvailableWorldwide": false,
      "testingInstructions": "...",
      "category": "SMART_HOME",
      "distributionCountries": [
        "US"
      ]
    },
    "apis": {
      "smartHome": {
        "endpoint": {
          "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:..."
        },
        "protocolVersion": "3"
      }
    },
    "manifestVersion": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "alexa::async_event:write"
      }
    ],
    "privacyAndCompliance": {
      "allowsPurchases": false,
      "locales": {
        "en-US": {
          "termsOfUseUrl": "...",
          "privacyPolicyUrl": "..."
        }
      },
      "isExportCompliant": true,
      "containsAds": false,
      "isChildDirected": false,
      "usesPersonalInfo": false
    },
    "events": {
      "endpoint": {
        "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:..."
      },
      "subscriptions": [
        {
          "eventName": "SKILL_ENABLED"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "SKILL_DISABLED"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "SKILL_PERMISSION_ACCEPTED"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "SKILL_PERMISSION_CHANGED"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "SKILL_ACCOUNT_LINKED"
        }
      ],
      "regions": {
        "NA": {
          "endpoint": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:..."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works for `Smart home` type of skills

Comment: It works for my Smart Home skill. P.S. you do need to add the `Alexa Skills Kit` trigger to your lambda.

Comment: Added "Alexa Skills Kit" besides the already added "Alexa Smart Home" trigger for lambda, don't see any new events in CloudWatch. Have you set up anything additionally? My lambda only consists of "index.js" file that parses the requests.

Comment: You've updated your Skill manifest according to the documentation, right? If you try to update it before adding the `Alexa Skills Kit` trigger, the update would fail. Check the update status to ensure the upload was successful.

Comment: Thanks, was able to add the event, but now have a follow up question

Comment: Hi @RenārsVilnis, you should update the original post with your updates instead of editing my response...Regardless, I have not used `ask deploy` so I don't know for sure, but I suspect that warning message is expected for Smart Home Skills because account linking is required, it cannot auto enable the Skill for you. I would suggest you to post a new question so others can chime in.